# Manage VSS to SVN migration

Tags: svn, visual-sourcesafe

Our organization is making a migration from VSS to SVN.

Now, due the lack of branching on VSS there's a folder with the source code from the last production environment code it was used like a queue where the new code was pushed to the top of the queue then it basically depended on a very manual thing and it was all or nothing scenario.

To migrate a C# migration tool was used to upload the current code of the VSS to the 
SVN it worked ok and the file change history was kept.

How to deal with this scenario? where the current VSS code was uploaded to the trunk, this  because the file history it's required to be kept, and the code of the production environment will be a branch but with previous versions of the files and less functions than the trunk, and then be able to merge this 2 roots.

Thanks for your comments.

PD. The production code has a requirements change now, i cannot use the current trunk to make a new production code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you label in VSS? If so, it would probably work best if you made your production branch from a corresponding revision in the svn trunk so that the repository knew there was a shared history.

Either way, you should be able to merge trunk changes into the production branch.

I would suggest reading up on [Branching and Merging](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.html) in the SVN Book as well. It is well written and can be a lot of help.

**Edit:** If you need to change production separately from the trunk, you should still be able to merge changes later, but you probably also need to consider the need for putting the production changes into the trunk. This might help prevent some merge issues later, plus then the trunk would also be more up to date with bug fixes, etc.

Comment: he production code has a requirements change now, i cannot use the current trunk to make a new production code.

Comment: you can make the production changes on the production branch you create based on the label